# How to draw an orthogonal graph from its edges and vertices data?

Tags: algorithm, vector-graphics

I am writing a software and I need to represent an graph in a orthogonal manner from topological data (vector of edges,vertices and their connectivity data)

**Graphs** consist of a set of **vertices** and a set of **edges**, each connecting two vertices.A vertex may have any number of connected edges so it makes the problem a lot more complicated.

I have read some articles and its looks like that the **Kandinsky model** is the post popular one. However I just don't know the algorithm, any other solution (algorithm) that solve the problem is also very welcome.

---

**Added after edit**

The following picture shows a real world example for an electricity network which should be considered as raw data, in order to create a graph from this network, some preliminary tasks must be done.

Input Data:

[image: Input Data]

The result I am looking for is something like below, 
there are some characteristics if you take a look much closer :

The Red Polygon in the middle of the above picture(input data) represents an electricity substation which is a node itself and can be connected to more than 4 edges.
There are more red polygons but only one can be fit into the above picture however as you may see, the following picture could cover much more than a red polygon that means it can map a bigger area, so the following picture is much more denser.

In Schematics diagrams, red polygons (Substations) usually maintain their position against each other relatively so if we manage to see beyond the extents of the above map by zooming out for example, we should almost see a triangle that is obviously can be seen at the below while having the left one at the left, the down one at the down ..... (this is not a rule, but I thought it could be a head start for desired algorithm)

Orthogonal Diagram:

[image: Orthogonal Schematic]

Comment: Does orthogonal in this context mean using only vertical and horizontal edges? Are you looking for a way to represent more than 4 edges meeting at a single vertex?

Comment: @trichoplax Exactly, and I do appreciate any help.

Comment: Is the graph guaranteed to be planar so that, forgetting the orthogonal edges for a moment, the graph can be drawn without edges overlapping?

Comment: General graph layout algorithms are anoying to program and implement. Even just finding proper ones from literature is pain. You should describe a bit more what you expect, draw a picture.

Comment: @DanielMGessel It is an electricity network and I have the real world map(coordinates) in hand, The graph is planar and maybe the edges cross each other, so its not a problem if the orthogonal edges cross each other, because in some case I believe there is no way to draw the graph without overlapping edges.

Comment: @joojaa I have GIS data of an electricity network and just like any electricity computation software(cyme, digsilent, pti,...) I just need to draw an arc-node structure in an orthogonal manner. As I described above for Daniel. I have extracted the hypernodes and their connections so the ortho graph could be drawn from sketch using these data. I will attach some picture to the question to increase the clearity, thanks for suggesting.

Comment: The vertexes already have a given position in 2D (or on a sphere), so it's more of an edge routing problem? The trivial solution is to route each edge first along the x, then along the y axis (or the other way 'round). If this is right, explaining the problems with this trivial solution might be helpful. I imagine a minimization problem by assigning penalties for the problems...

Comment: @DanielMGessel I have added some pictures and explanation, hope it clear the ambiguities.

Comment: @joojaa Please take a look at the added picture.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**libCola**

cola.js (a.k.a. WebCola) is a JavaScript based rewrite of libcola which works well with D3.js

http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/

Gridified Layout example:

http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/dotpowergraph.html

**OGDF**

Open Graph Drawing Framework

Have an orthogonal layout

> Orthogonal: Ortholayout with modules for the steps of shape and
>   compaction, ClusterOrthoLayout

http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/ogdf:features

Check projects that uses OGDF

http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/project:external

**HOLA**

Human-like Orthogonal Layout Algorithm

https://vimeo.com/150509722

Kieffer, Steve, Tim Dwyer, Kim Marriott, and Michael Wybrow. "Hola: Human-like orthogonal network layout." Visualization and Computer Graphics, IEEE Transactions on 22, no. 1 (2016): 349-358.

Comment: This sounds promising. Could you edit to add some detail of what this provides?

Comment: It would also be useful to have an overview of how each algorithm works, so that they can be compared without needing to leave the answer.